# Target 'Android 1.5' does not support building project with libraries

Tags: android, build, reference, project

I'm trying to build a project in Android 1.5 that references another Android (library) project compiled against Android 1.5 and I keep seeing this error in the Console in Eclipse:

Target 'Android 1.5' does not support building project with libraries.

I'm running Eclipse 3.5, and version 0.9.7 of the ADT.

I followed the instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

What gives?

Comment: Is "SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4" listed in the Android SDK Installed Packages?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that's the problem. I had revision 3. I'm trying to update to revision 4 and now I've got another problem, it's failing to install, saying that a folder failed to be renamed or moved. It says something might be accessing 'C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-1.5', although I don't know what. I closed all my projects so nothing is open in Eclipse. FYI I'm using the Android SDK and AVD manager to do the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong revision of Android 1.5. Table 1 on this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

states that you must be using revision 4 or later of Android 1.5 to use Library projects.